# run multiple parity clients in parallel

Tags: go-ethereum, parity, synchronization, light-clients, warp-sync

How can I run multiple parity instances on one machine? With geth it's easy. I just have to set different `--port` numbers. What's the equivalent for parity?

I want to recreate [Afris scenario](https://twitter.com/5chdn/status/1081289013913370626).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `--jsonrpc-port` for HTTP interface and/or `--ws-port` for WebSocket interface.

Comment: Thanks! I also just found [this](https://gist.github.com/5chdn/61e156216fcd316fb4bc0bfcf0259531) which works with `--ports-shift <value>`.